# Discord.py Bot JSON File not Saving

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I am working on a basic Discord Bot to manage some very simple data. I have a database.json file in my bot's directory. For some reason, the information appears to be being saved, however when I view the json file with textedit/VScode, the file is empty. I am just wondering if there is anything that I am doing wrong that would be causing the json data to not be shown in the database.json file. The data appears to be being saved, as it is not deleted when I stop/start the bot, but again, the json database file is completely blank.

Let me know if you have any ideas. :)

````
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)

database = []

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, email, status):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.status = status

def load_database():
    try:
        with open('database.json', 'r') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            for entry in data:
                add_person(entry['name'], entry['email'], entry['status'])
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

def save_database():
    with open('database.json', 'w') as file:
        data = []
        for person in database:
            data.append({"name": person.name, "email": person.email, "status": person.status})
        json.dump(data, file)
        file.close()
        print("Data saved:", data)

def add_person(name, email, status):
    person = Person(name, email, status)
    database.append(person)
    save_database()

def remove_person(name):
    for person in database:
        if person.name == name:
            database.remove(person)
            save_database()
            return True
    return False

def purge_all():
    database.clear()
    save_database()

def get_person(name):
    for person in database:
        if person.name == name:
            return person
    return None

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    load_database()
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.command()
async def dbcommands(ctx):
    """List all available commands with descriptions."""
    commands_info = [
        ("/dbcommands", "List all available commands with descriptions."),
        ("/dbadd", "Add a person to the database. Use format: /dbadd name:<name>,email:<email>,status:<status>"),
        ("/dbprint", "Print the database."),
        ("/dbremove", "Remove a person from the database. Use format: /dbremove <name>"),
        ("/dbpurgeall", "Delete the entire database. Type 'y' to confirm or 'n' to cancel."),
        ("/dbsave", "Manually save changes to the database JSON file.")
    ]
    
    help_message = "\n".join([f"{command} - {description}" for command, description in commands_info])
    await ctx.send(f"```{help_message}```")

@bot.command()
async def dbprint(ctx):
    """Print the database."""
    if not database:
        await ctx.send("The database is empty.")
        return

    for person in database:
        await ctx.send(f"Name: {person.name}, Email: {person.email}, Status: {person.status}")

@bot.command()
async def dbadd(ctx, *, args):
    """Add a person to the database."""
    args_list = args.split(',')
    person_info = {}

    for arg in args_list:
        key, value = arg.split(':')
        person_info[key] = value

    if 'name' not in person_info or 'email' not in person_info or 'status' not in person_info:
        await ctx.send("Invalid arguments. Use format: /dbadd name:<name>,email:<email>,status:<status>")
        return

    add_person(person_info['name'], person_info['email'], person_info['status'])
    await ctx.send("Person added to the database.")

@bot.command()
async def dbremove(ctx, name):
    """Remove a person from the database."""
    if not name:
        await ctx.send("Please provide a name to remove from the database.")
        return

    if remove_person(name):
        await ctx.send(f"{name} removed from the database.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{name} not found in the database.")

@bot.command()
async def dbpurgeall(ctx):
    """Delete the entire database. Confirm with 'y' or 'n'."""
    await ctx.send("Are you sure you want to delete the entire database? Type 'y' for yes or 'n' for no.")
    
    def check(response):
        return response.author == ctx.author and response.content.lower() in ['y', 'n']

    try:
        response = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30)
        if response.content.lower() == 'y':
            purge_all()
            await ctx.send("Database purged.")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Database purge canceled.")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Timeout. Database purge canceled.")

@bot.command()
async def dbsave(ctx):
    """Manually save changes to the database JSON file."""
    save_database()
    await ctx.send("Changes saved to the database JSON file.")

@bot.command()
async def dbshutdown(ctx):
    """Shut down the bot."""
    await ctx.send("Shutting down the bot...")
    await bot.close()

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("Command not found.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Missing arguments. Use the command as specified.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"An error occurred while processing the command: {error}")

bot.run('token')```
````

Comment: _I have a database.json file in my bot's directory_ Your code opens `database.json` in the **current directory**, which is not necessarily the same directory as the bot code.  I would guess that it is actually opening that same filename in some other directory.  You can use this to see the real current directory `import os; print(os.getcwd())`